# Use a vector/index as a row name in a dataframe using rbind

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I think I'm missing something super simple, but I seem to be unable to find a solution directly relating to what I need: I've got a data frame that has a letter as the row name and a two columns of numerical values. As part of a loop I'm running I create a new vector (from an index) that has both a letter and number (e.g. "f2") which I then need to be the name of a new row, then add two numbers next to it (based on some other section of code, but I'm fine with that). What I get instead is the name of the vector/index as the title of the row name, and I'm not sure if I'm missing a function of rbind or something else to make it easy.

Example code:

```
#Data frame and vector creation
row.names <- letters[1:5]
vector.1 <- c(1:5)
vector.2 <- c(2:6)
vector.3 <- letters[6:10]
data.frame <- data.frame(vector.1,vector.2)
rownames(data.frame) <- row.names
data.frame

index.vector <- "f2" 

#what I want the data frame to look like with the new row
data.frame <- rbind(data.frame, "f2" = c(6,11))
data.frame

#what the data frame looks like when I attempt to use a vector as a row name
data.frame <- rbind(data.frame, index.vector = c(6,11))
data.frame

#"why" I can't just type "f" every time
index.vector2 = paste(index.vector, "2", sep="")
data.frame <- rbind(data.frame, index.vector2 = c(6,11))
data.frame
```

In my loop the "index.vector" is a random sample, hence where I can't just write the letter/number in as a row name, so need to be able to create the row name from a vector or from the index of the sample.

The loop runs and a random number of new rows will be created, so I can't specify what number the row is that needs a new name - unless there's a way to just do it for the newest or bottom row every time.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not elegant, but works:

```
new_row <- data.frame(setNames(list(6, 11), colnames(data.frame)), row.names = paste(index.vector, "2", sep=""))
data.frame <- rbind(data.frame, new_row)
data.frame
# vector.1 vector.2
# a          1        2
# b          2        3
# c          3        4
# d          4        5
# e          5        6
# f22        6       11
```

Comment: Works exactly how I need, thank you very much.

And trust me when I say my code is basically elegance-free already, this won't be any different. Will probably be the most elegant bit in it!

Answer (score 1):

I Understood the problem , but not able to resolve the issue. Hence, suggesting an alternative way to achieve the same

**Alternate solution:** append your  row labels after the data binding in your loop and then assign the row names to your dataframe at the end .

```
  #Data frame and vector creation

    row.names <- letters[1:5]
    vector.1 <- c(1:5)
    vector.2 <- c(2:6)
    vector.3 <- letters[6:10]

    data.frame <- data.frame(vector.1,vector.2)

    #loop starts
     index.vector <- "f2" 
     data.frame <- rbind(data.frame,c(6,11))  
     row.names<-append(row.names,index.vector)
    #loop ends 

   rownames(data.frame) <- row.names
   data.frame
```

output:

```
   vector.1 vector.2
a         1        2
b         2        3
c         3        4
d         4        5
e         5        6
f2        6       11
```

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for this, it did work but I have gone with @alex 's solution as it fits into my existing code a bit neater.

Answer (score 0):

If you manipulate the data frame with `rbind`, then the newest elements will always be at the "bottom" of your data frame. Hence you could also set a single row name by

```
rownnames(data.frame)[nrow(data.frame)] = "new_name"
```

Comment: Super simple thing to tag on the end, thank you very much!